# How to download commons.lang with Play framework?

Tags: java, maven, playframework, apache-commons, ivy

I have the following configuration (shortened) in the dependencies file of my Play! application:

```
require:
    - play
    - org.apache.commons -> commons.lang3 3.1

repositories:
    - maven:
        type: iBiblio
        root: "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
        contains:
            - org.apache.commons -> commons.lang3
```

However, Play! is not able to fetch the commons.lang package. I get the error message:

```
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: org.apache.commons#commons.lang3;3.1

        ==== maven: tried

          http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons.lang3/3.1/commons.lang3-3.1.pom
          -- artifact org.apache.commons#commons.lang3;3.1!commons.lang3.jar:

          http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons.lang3/3.1/commons.lang3-3.1.jar
                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.apache.commons#commons.lang3;3.1: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Following [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.commons%7Ccommons-lang3%7C3.1%7Cjar) it should be in the central repository.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Commons Lang artifactId is commons-lang3 instead of commons.lang3. So the URL is http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.pom instead of http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons.lang3/3.1/commons.lang3-3.1.pom